# How to send log using logging to slack as message in python and flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, flask, slack-api

Give me solution how can i get log directly to slack channel using **python and flask**.I am able to use **logging** and save it in log file but i want that **info,warning,error,critical,debug logs** should directly send to slack channel.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of sending a message to a Slack channel via. Python. You must have a Slack web hook configured for your Slack group, which you can then add onto the `hook` var.

```
import json, requests

def sendMessageToSlack():
    hook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<hook goes here>"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {"attachments":[
                  {
                    "fallback":"",
                    "pretext":"",
                    "color":"#fff",
                    "fields":[
                         {
                             "title":"",
                             "value":"",
                             "short": False
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }

      r = requests.post(hook, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
      print("Response: " + str(r.status_code) + "," +  str(r.reason))
```

Providing the response returns a 200 code, you should have a message in your channel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to utilize `flask`...

I think you can just use [Slack API client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) together with its [Documentation](http://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/). Basic usage is what you're looking for (coloring etc.).

Using your own solutions isn't recommended - sometimes API changes and you would have to maintain it. Official API client gives you level of abstraction and you don't have to worry about sudden errors.

Posting message (copied from github):

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
  "chat.postMessage",
  channel="#python",
  text="Hello from Python! :tada:"
)
```

You can generate test token on [this website](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) and try it for yourself.